# Send message to inbox of member of group who I'm not friends with

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-messenger

I need to reach members of my group whom I am not friends with and who may have turned off notifications (I don't want to friend them though). Is there a way to get a message to their inbox (not their *Others* inbox of messages) or something equally as noticeable (email?) ?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is to click on "See more" option & tick a mark which offers to send the message directly to the inbox. This, however, is not free & you'll be charged.

[image]

There's no other way to send the message to their inbox